# Recycler View leaving huge space before printing next card view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

> > > > > I'm trying to show all the card views using recycler view in main activity. Although I did not set a huge margin between card views, my recycler view shows a huge space to print the next card view. please see my attached image, you'll understand what I'm trying to say. I've attached all the code here. Can you please advise how to solve this problem? Thank you.

[image]

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:listitem="@layout/note_card" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/add" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/green"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTitleCard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewDescriptionCard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    package com.destructivepaul.quicknote;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NoteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.NoteHolder>{
    private List<MyNote> myNoteList = new ArrayList<>();
   // private Context context;

    public void setMyNoteList(List<MyNote> myNoteList) {
        this.myNoteList = myNoteList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.i("info","note updated on adapter. note list size: "+myNoteList.size());

    }

    //public void setContext(Context context) {
    //    this.context = context;
       // notifyDataSetChanged();
    //    Log.i("info","context updated on adapter");

   // }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NoteHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.note_card
        ,parent,false);
        return new NoteHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteHolder holder, int position) {
        MyNote myNote=myNoteList.get(position);
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(myNote.getNote_title());
        holder.textViewDescription.setText(myNote.getNote_description());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return myNoteList.size();


    }


   public class NoteHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView textViewTitle, textViewDescription;
        private CardView cardView;
       public NoteHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
           super(itemView);

           textViewTitle=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitleCard);
           textViewDescription=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDescriptionCard);
           cardView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
           Log.i("info","card design found on adapter");



       }
   }
}


    package com.destructivepaul.quicknote;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MyNoteViewModel myNoteViewModel;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncherForAddNote;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //resisterActivity
        resisterActivityForAddNote();

        fab=findViewById(R.id.fab);
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        NoteAdapter adapter=new NoteAdapter();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.i("info","set the adapter");


        myNoteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication())
                .create(MyNoteViewModel.class);
        myNoteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(MainActivity.this, new Observer<List<MyNote>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<MyNote> myNotes) {

                adapter.setMyNoteList(myNotes);
                Log.i("info","adapter is called to update data");


            }
        });
      

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,CreateNoteActivity.class);
                //resister activity launcher
                activityResultLauncherForAddNote.launch(intent);
               Log.i("info","called resister activity launcher on fab");


            }
        });



    }
    public void resisterActivityForAddNote(){
        activityResultLauncherForAddNote=registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
                , new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                        int resultCode=result.getResultCode();
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        if (resultCode==RESULT_OK && data !=null) {
                            String title = data.getStringExtra("title");
                            String description = data.getStringExtra("description");
                            String colorName = data.getStringExtra("color");
                            MyNote myNote = new MyNote(title, description, colorName);
                            Log.i("info", "new note created on activity result");

                            myNoteViewModel.insert(myNote);
                            Log.i("info", "note saved to database");

                        }

                    }
                });

    }
}
```

Comment: I've solved my problem by myself.  The problem was on card layout design(parent layout height should be wrap content instead of match parent).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by myself. The problem was on card layout design(parent layout height should be wrap content instead of match parent).